# Version of `imp.find_module` that works on dotted modules

Tags: python, import

Is there an *existing* implementation of [`imp.find_module`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) that works on dotted module names? It doesn't need to be bulletproof, it's okay if it won't work for some cases. But the more cases it works for, the better.

And please, don't try to implement this function in an answer. I've already implemented my version of it, I'm asking if there's an *existing* implementation because if there is one, it's probably much more tested than my version.

Answer (score 5):

[importlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib) might be what you're after. In particular the function `import_module`. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) say:

> `importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`
>
> Import a module. The *name* argument specifies what module to import in absolute or relative terms (e.g. either `pkg.mod` or `..mod`). If the name is specified in relative terms, then the *package* argument must be set to the name of the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name (e.g. `import_module('..mod', 'pkg.subpkg'`) will import `pkg.mod`)

Comment: The problem with this is that `importlib.import_module` successfully finds the module even if only the `.pyc` file still exists. So you can 't use this if you specifically wanted to check if the module's `.py` file exists on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

For others viewing this question and looking for a method, here's what I'm using.

```
import imp

def find_dotted_module(name, path=None):
    res = None
    for x in name.split('.'):
        res = imp.find_module(x, path)
        path = [module[1]]
    return res
```

Comment: and `module[1]` is what again?

Comment: @Michael Waterfall there is an undefined variable: `module`: I added my implementation, based on yours, below.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_dotted_module(name, path=None):
    '''
    Example: find_dotted_module('mypackage.myfile')

    Background: imp.find_module() does not handle hierarchical module names (names containing dots).

    Important: No code of the module gets executed. The module does not get loaded (on purpose)
    ImportError gets raised if the module can't be found.

    Use case: Test discovery without loading (otherwise coverage does not see the lines which are executed 
              at import time)
    '''

    for x in name.split('.'):
        if path is not None:
            path=[path]
        file, path, descr = imp.find_module(x, path)
    return path
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried the following from the documentation of `imp.find_module`?

> This function does not handle
>   hierarchical module names (names
>   containing dots). In order to find
>   P.*M*, that is, submodule M of package
>   P, use find_module() and load_module()
>   to find and load package P, and then
>   use find_module() with the path
>   argument set to P.__ path__. When P
>   itself has a dotted name, apply this
>   recipe recursively.

Comment: I want a solution that works without loading the parent. Yes, I know, it would miss a few cases, but I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know what you are doing and you think imp inspection is too complicated, how about this:

```py
        if not all([x.isalnum() or x == '.' for x in name]):
            raise ValueError('invalid module name')
        exec("import %s" % name)
```